# C Program explanation

Tags: python, c

I am working on a parsing program in C and Python and am wondering if someone can explain exactly what is being done in this program. The primary goal is to generate a binary blob in the test.bin file from scratch and write the following data to it. Can someone explain what the hex values are telling the program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file;

    int i;
    int buffer[] = {

        0x00000003, 0x01000506, 0x03000809, 0x02000606,
        0x04000503, 0x04000506, 0x07000809, 0x09000607,
        0x09000803, 0x04000506, 0x07000809, 0x09000608,
    };  

    file = fopen("test.bin", "wb");

    if (file != NULL)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(buffer); i++)
        {
            fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(int), 1, file);
        }

        fclose(file);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may wish to clarify your question and reduce the size of your examples to the minimum code that can show an example of your question.  You should also specific the bit size of the machine, the OS and the compiler you are using (for the C code), as int may be a different size (32/64) based on these factors.  Your examples seem to assume everything is 32 bits.

Comment: That's fair, I will start smaller. Editing now.

Answer (score 2):

They're not "telling" anything to the program. The program is writing them in machine order to a file on disk.

Comment: Well "them" – only the very first value, as many as there values are in that array.

Comment: True, but I'm sure they'll catch that thinko soon enough.

Comment: I'm new to C, so it's a bit hard for me to grasp. Can you expand on the "very first value" ?

Comment: It repeatedly writes `0x00000003`. You want `buffer+i` there, no need for the `&`.